# jQuery Isotope - prevent Isotope from doing the initial transition

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope with css such as

```
.isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

which makes my layout do a 0.8 transition even into the initial state. I'd like it not to transition initially, but keep the 0.8s transition on resize or add item

Answer (score 0):

why don't you rap the transition in a media screen so that for example if your isotope container is 980px;

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 981px) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

the transition will only occur between 0-980px's

Comment: I dont think that does anything for me. I dont want the transitions on initial layout, no matter the width and height of the container

Answer (score 0):

Avoid having the `.isotope` class applied to the container initially by setting the option `containerClass` to an empty string initially and then setting the `.isotope` class on the container after the initial layout has occurred.

```
var containerClassSet = false,
    $container = $('#container');
$container.isotope({
    containerClass: '',
    onLayout:       function ($elems, instance) {
        if (!containerClassSet) {
            containerClassSet = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $container.addClass('isotope');
            }, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Ensuring that your classes are prefixed with `.isotope`:

```
.isotope .isotope-item {
    ...
}
```